# How do I read an entire directory of text files into memory quickly in Java?

Tags: java, performance, unix, filesystems

I am running a Java program which reads 1-2000000 text files and does a simple operation for each of them and writes them back to disk.
On my Windows laptop this takes 8 minutes for operation on 40,000 files.
on an old Solaris system, which has a UFS file system, it took 12 hours.

After consulting with an IT guy he suggested the issue is due to the file structure in UFS which requires a sequential seek.

I would like to read all the files in the order they appear on the FS, therefore removing the need to seek each time.
How would I go about that ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `listFiles()` method in `File` to get a list of all the files in that directory.

Comment: The most obvious optimization seems to me to be multithreading, if you're currently doing all this in a single thread.

Comment: @codebolt: If this is IO-bound, that will quite possibly make it slower rather than faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider

```
MappedByteBuffer
```

Try also to optimize buffer sizes (how big are the chunks you read at a time?)